# Swift 3: Upload Image to cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, image, cloudkit

I have an image (stored in a UIImage format) that I want to update to a record on CloudKit. How do I update this record? Do i need to convert to temporary url?

Comment: Upload it as an asset. CKAssets are used to store large files like images.